# Send teams message to a user using c# code

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I want to send teams message to an user using c# code. Is there any way if we can achieve this? If yes please share me some code snippet or the links which will guide me to achieve the same.

Regards,
Satish

Comment: Did you try doing any research around this? Did you try writing and code for this? What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: Please share your code what did you try.

Answer (score 1):

For Microsoft Graph API beta you can send a message in a chat:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var chatMessage = new ChatMessage
{
    Body = new ItemBody
    {
        Content = "Hello world"
    }
};

await graphClient.Users["{id}"].Chats["{id}"].Messages
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(chatMessage);
```

For more info read [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: Could I know what is chats["{id}"] ?

Comment: Creating a new chat is not supported by API. You have find the existing chat with a specific user and then use the correct chat id to send a message.